# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE not working - File not found (MySQL Workbench)

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am using the below command to load an excel file to MySQL server:

```sql
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'GPMO_Resource_Download_report_CSV'
INTO TABLE gpmo_resource_download_report_1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

I have this file on the same machine at the below path:

```
C:\Users\aprakas2\Desktop\Task\GPMO_Resource_Download_report_CSV
```

Please suggest me how should I load this file ?

Comment: use the absolute file path...

Answer (score 0):

I think these SQL will useful to you.

If file has header row

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Users/aprakas2/Desktop/Task/GPMO_Resource_Download_report_CSV' 
INTO TABLE gpmo_resource_download_report_1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

If file has no header row

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Users/aprakas2/Desktop/Task/GPMO_Resource_Download_report_CSV' 
INTO TABLE gpmo_resource_download_report_1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Thank you.